# ios screen flickering after magnifying glass hover

Tags: ios, uitextview

I got this app with a text field (actually a `UITextView`) for entering text. Above this text field is a tableView list of chat messages.

There is this very odd behaviour whereby I long press on my text field to edit my existing text and after hovering the magnifying glass around the screen, some of the text in the tableView list of chat messages starts to flicker.

Even the nav title text gets cut off half way (depending on how much of the magnifying glass overlaps it) and starts flickering.

I've tried to use the 3D layer viewer in Xcode to find out if there are any overlapping views that could cause it but nothing, no view is obscuring the other views.

It's like some sort of graphics context clipping problem wherever the magnifying glass goes.

Has else anyone seen this problem before ?

Edit:

Here's a screenshot of what happens to the screen.

[image: screen flicker screenshot]

As you can see the nav title should say "Tim" but it gets clipped.

Some of the chat messages disappear for a split second.

To the left of "Message" should be another button but that too is flickering.

### New Discovery!

I have tracked down the problem and it appears to be caused by this third party library called SlideMenuController:

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

I downloaded the library and added a `UITextView` to FriendsViewController.m and ran the app, brought up the magnifying glass and it cause the screen to flicker like above screenshot.

I'll continue digging, hopefully I can find a fix for it.

Comment: Latest iOS 8.3 (12F70)

Comment: tried restarting app and rebooting device?

Comment: Yes. It's happening on multiple devices we tested it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :D

So it was the SlideMenuController library that was causing the issue somehow.

The solution I came up with was to change `SlideNavigationController.m` **line 117** from:

```
self.enableShadow = YES;
```

to

```
self.enableShadow = NO;
```

Hope that helps anyone else having the same problem :D